# Resource that gives examples of many different sentences described in tree diagrams

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, resource-request

I've devoured the book "Beginning Syntax" by Linda Thomas, but there are areas it doesn't go into in enough depth (presumably to keep it simple).  For example, modal auxiliary "ought to" - it doesn't explain how to parse that in the sentence tree. It seems like a group of it's own rather than one single MOD.

If there is a website that has many examples of different sentences described in UK style  trees diagrams that would be super helpful.  Obviously I have searched myself but haven't found what I'm looking for.

Thanks for any recommendations or thoughts - maybe a book if no website exists?

Comment: Probably you're ready for [McCawley 1998](http://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), then.

Comment: Carnie's book "Syntax A Generative Introduction" (2006) will help you, I think

Comment: Except that McCawley's book is a complete syntax of English as well.

Comment: @Jlawler, I now have volume 1 (1988) of McCawley's book. I do not think it is as good as you repeatedly suggest in this forum. McCawley makes the same sort of mistakes that most other constituency grammars make. For instance, he is useing the one-diagnostic and the do-so-diagnostics as tests for constituents. More importantly, he mentions dependency-based syntax only briefly.

Comment: Linda Thomas' book is really very basic, and I think it makes a couple of important errors when it comes to presenting the concept of syntax at a basic level. For instance, it construes finite "did" alone (i.e. without an object) as a pro-verb, when it is in fact an auxiliary in such cases.  After having read Thomas' book, I think you are now ready for Burton-Roberts book (1997): "Analysing sentences". This book is more accessible than McCawley's two-volume oeuvre.

Comment: 1988 is the first edition. 1998 is the second one-volume edition. And dependency-based grammar should be mentioned only when it provides a superior analysis.

Comment: @Jlawler, my view is of course that dependency is producing the superior analysis most of the time. Constituency is needed for coordination, but not for subordination. The problem with McCawley's generation is that it was not fully exposed to dependency-based syntax in the early days (1960s). Once committed to the subject-predicate division, it's difficult to see syntax in terms of dependencies. The syntax world continues to struggle terribly with this oversight. My opinion, of course.

Comment: @Jlawler, I intend to get a copy of McCawley's (1998) volume. I will enjoy touching on specific points from the volume when you bring it up in the future.

Comment: Whatever. If you prefer something else, that's your privilege. But others don't always share your sense of satisfaction with dependency grammars. No grammar that ignores any important variety of organization is perfect. In fact, no grammar is perfect.

Comment: @Jlawler, many others have hardly been exposed to dependency grammar. That's the problem, in my view.

Comment: Thanks for your contributions, these are great suggestions for me to look into some more.